asp.net core RequestTimeouts WriteTimeoutResponse unexecuted
Using asp.net core RequestTimeouts middleware,set default policy. The status code was assigned normally, but the response body did not return correctly. API in independent controller
Config:

Controller:

Enviroment：asp.net core 8.0
api response is empty

Please paste your code as text not images. See [faq]s and try to provide a [mcve].

ContentType needs to be configured. Also change status code to a unique one to verify if the middleware really works.
If we want to run and test this locally, we need to detach the debug process otherwise the timeouts won’t apply. Try start without debugging.
var defaultPolicy = new RequestTimeoutPolicy
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    TimeoutStatusCode = 707,
    WriteTimeoutResponse = async (HttpContext context) =>
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Response Output : Time Out");
    }
};


